# why NSMutableArray Always error when allo init autorelease at init class?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

Somewhere on .h I put

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * BusinessQueue;

-(BNUtilitiesQuick *) init {
        if (!(self = [super init]))
        {
            return nil;
        }//if the superclass is NSObject, this must be init
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]autorelease];
        BusinessQueue = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease]; 
        return self; //and return the object itself
    }
```

The way I see it `BusinessQueue = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];`  will make reference count 1. 1 for alloc. -1 for autorelease (sometimes latter) and 1 because BusinessQueue is a retain property.

However, BusinessQueue will get deallocated sometimes usually.

Why BusinessQueue always error but location manager doesn't

any wrong code? or NSMutableArray Can't be declared at init class?

Comment: you put the function in your .h header?   
do you @synthesize BusinessQueue?   
its not used to begin variables with Uppercase   
try 

    self.BusinessQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
and at least you retain BusinessQueue already in the property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BusinessQueue` is not a property.  `self.BusinessQueue` may be, if you defined it that way.

### Added:

And the best/simplest way to do the initialization is:

```
self.businessQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: That's another thing I noticed. Sometimes I can call property without self. Hmm... Perhaps if I just do BusinessQueue then it's assigning the variable straight without retaining.

Comment: When you refer to a field in your object without "self" you're referring to the FIELD, not the PROPERTY.  There's a difference.  The FIELD is just that -- no code is called and you reference it directly.  The PROPERTY has setter and getter methods behind it that, if so instructed, do `retain`.